# Kotlin Gradle Spring bootRun task with command line argument

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

I have a Kotlin Spring boot app with command line runner like following.

```
@SpringBootApplication
class MySpringApplication : CommandLineRunner {
  override fun run(vararg args: String?) {
    println(args[0])
  }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val app = SpringApplication(MySpringApplication::class.java)
  app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF)
  app.run(*args)
}
```

I am wondering how can I pass the command line args when I use the gradle command, `./gradlew bootRun`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you'll need to modify your `build.gradle` script to manually pass command line arguments into the `bootRun` task.

Find or create a `bootRun` configuration within you main `build.gradle` script and pass system properties into bootRun as follows:

```
bootRun {
  systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

Now you can start your app with command line arguments, which will be passed into you application:

```
./gradlew -DsomeProperty=true -q bootRun
```